# Full height side by side images in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to obtain the structure exemplified in the image bellow. There will be a full width & height container with 2 images and other elements inside. My images should be full-height(the height of container) and auto-width inside the container(growing from center to left, respectively to the right). My problem is that my images are much higher than container and I need to limit them somehow to be inside the container(red area) also to fill the full height of it. [image: desired structure]
PS.1 All images are in portrait mode and all of them have same height.
PS.2 I had a look at the other questions on Stack.
PS.3 You got [here](https://www.bootply.com/quRW1u3Luk) my non working example.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define flex for your desired result. 'justify-content' as center will center your images with equal margin on both sides.

PS. Add the 50% width to the images if you want the entire div to be covered.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  height: inherit;
}

#img1,
#img2 {
  height: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="child">

    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/36/66/76/3666764312573a54adef888747d0c8f3.jpg" id="img1">


    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/64/07/19/640719d42a8107720d760349fcfbbd52.jpg" id="img2">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but unfortunately did not solve my problem.  Please note that the outer container is full size and fully visible and I need my images to be scaled to the height of the container so there will be no scroll and no fixed height for them. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Considering the height of your outer container to be 300px, 'align-items' as stretch will force the images to take the entire height of the parent div. refer the edited post.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help.!

Answer (score 0):

Set the container-fluid and row to height 100% and remove the class "img-responsive". Also set the images to max-height:100% and max-width:100%

Working code

```
    <div class="pop-us-container">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="pop-up-1" class="col-sm-6 text-right">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1250/1730/">
          </div>
          <div id="pop-up-2" class="col-sm-6 text-left">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1250/1730/">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And CSS add

```
img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
.container-fluid, .row {
    height: 100%;
}
```

See a working example [here](https://www.bootply.com/PGvR3ROhdV).

Comment: Not working. Please note that the images should be inside the .pop-us-container div and their height should be the all the height available inside that container(image height = container height - container padding top - container padding bottom). Thank you for your time!

Comment: I updated my answer, please have a look if this works for you.

Comment: I've tried the changes that you suggested, but still not the desired effect.  Here you can find the final solution for what I wanted https://www.bootply.com/T8X211B34e . Thank you for your time!